# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined when deployed but not locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mongodb-atlas

I have created a MongoDB Atlas Cluster, put some data in there, then created a node/express app to retrieve data from that cluster. Locally I am able to retrieve the correct data but when my node server is deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

I'm unsure of how to even trace this problem I am having.

```html
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let database;

MongoClient.connect(
  'url-to-cluster',
  {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},
  (err, client) => {
    const users = client.db('entity');
    database = users.collection('entityinfo');
  });
  
  // Used in app.use method
  database.find().toArray()
    .then(results => {
      res.json(results[0].UID);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `MongoClient.connect` is asynchronous, it will return immediately and call the provided callback only after the connection resolves.

To demonstrate this, add log messages before the call to connect, inside the callback, and before the call to find.  I believe you will discover that find is being called before the callback that would give `database` a value.

This likely works locally because the connection completes fast enough that is it done before find is called, but takes several milliseconds (perhaps tens of milliseconds) when connecting to the server in the cloud.  i.e. this is a race condition.

You might try including the find call inside the callback, like

```
MongoClient.connect(
  'url-to-cluster',
  {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},
  (err, client) => {
    const users = client.db('entity');
    database = users.collection('entityinfo');
  
  // Used in app.use method
    database.find().toArray()
      .then(results => {
        res.json(results[0].UID);
      });
  });
```

Comment: So I tried this out, putting the find inside the callback method for the MongoClient.connect, and i was still getting the same error, except this time it was saying the returned client object within the callback is undefined. So somehow the deployed version is not able to connect to mongodb atlas correctly.

Comment: just solved the issue, I only had my local ip address white listed.